# How to import multiple json objects from a json file from a path into R as a dataframe

Tags: r

I have 1,307 JSON files in the path `"D:/a/b/c"`.
Each JSON file contains multiple rows.
Are there any ways to read all 1,307 JSON files in that path in one way?

Comment: Do you know how to read 1 JSON file ?

Comment: json_file <- ".json"
json_file_contents <- readLines(json_file)
json_file_contents <- paste(json_file_contents, collapse = ",")
json_file_contents <- paste(c("[", json_file_contents, "]"), collapse = "")
a = fromJSON(json_file_contents)

is this correct ?

Comment: Please add more details. Do the json files have the same format? And what format is it? Can we see a sample of the data? WIth so few details it is hard to help you, sorry.